# Getting error using WSO2 open ID connect after giving consent as "server_error: Error while handling consent"

Tags: openid, openid-connect, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Followed steps in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+Single+Sign-on+with+OpenID+Connect#fef2f9c7ed1c4a15babfeb25eafbbb3e for openID with single sign on 
getting error as below after the consent page :
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you check the wso2carbon logs? Any logs regarding this error?

Comment: yes no errors in the console..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got solved after adding consent dbscripts available in wso2 identity server code to the carbon database (i.e the user and reg db) used by the wso2